# Spacer between two views that can expand to max width

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to center two textviews horizontally to parent view and they should have space of 13dp between them. TextView1 is fixed, but TextView2 is dynamic, but predefined. On one case TextView2 is little longer, so it's being cutoff. Only in this case, how can I steal necessary width from the space, so that they all fit. Following is my solution, but I can't seem to prioritize Spacer view to take 13dp when available.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="FixedTextA" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_max="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="dynamicTextB" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I also tried `maxWdith` with `<View>` or `Space` on `LinearLayout`